# How can I speed up calculation of the integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics, numerical-value

Is it possible to speed up the calculation of the Kx integral?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Psi1[r_, z_] := Exp[-2*z^2]*(Exp[-1.3*r^2] + Exp[-4*r^2] + Exp[-2.3*r^2]);
NN = 1/Sqrt[Integrate[Psi1[r, z]*Psi1[r, z]*r*2*Pi, {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]];
Psi[r_, z_] := NN*Psi1[r, z];

Kk[r_, z_] := FullSimplify[Psi[r, z]*Laplacian[Psi[r, z], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"]*r*2*Pi];
Kx = -(1/2)*Integrate[Kk[r, z], {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}] //Timing

Out[42]= {5.375, 3.06865}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using for general:

$$\text{Psi1}(r,z)=\exp \left(-a z^2\right) \left(\exp \left(-b r^2\right)+\exp \left(-c r^2\right)+\exp \left(-d r^2\right)\right)$$

then we have:

```
Kx = -((b c (b + c) d (b + d) (c + 
  d) (2 (-3 - (8 b c)/(b + c)^2 + (8 b^2)/(b + d)^2 - (8 b)/(
     b + d) - (8 c d)/(c + d)^2) + 
  a (-(1/b) - 1/c - 4/(b + c) - 1/d - 4/(b + d) - 4/(c + d))))/(
2 (c^2 d^2 (c + d) + b^3 (c^2 + 6 c d + d^2) + 
  b^2 (c + d) (c^2 + 15 c d + d^2) + 
  2 b c d (3 c^2 + 8 c d + 3 d^2))));

a = 2; b = 13/10; c = 4; d = 23/10;

Kx
(*161819640529/52733231019*)
% // N
(*3.06865*)
```

Comment: Thanks, for useful answer!

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

Psi1[r_, z_] := Exp[-2*z^2]*(Exp[-1.3*r^2] + Exp[-4*r^2] + Exp[-2.3*r^2]);
NN = 1/Sqrt[
    Integrate[
     Psi1[r, z]*Psi1[r, z]*r*2*Pi, {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, 
      Infinity}]];
Psi[r_, z_] := NN*Psi1[r, z];
```

Putting `FullSimplify` on the RHS of `SetDelayed` results in the simplification being used for every call to `Kk`. Use `Set` to do the simplification only once

```
Kk[r_, z_] = 
  FullSimplify[
   Psi[r, z]*Laplacian[Psi[r, z], {r, θ, z}, "Cylindrical"]*r*2*Pi];
```

Note that the timing should be isolated from the definition of `Kx`

```
(Kx = -(1/2)*
    Integrate[
     Kk[r, z], {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {3.86644, 3.06865} *)
```

Since you introduced a machine precision number in the definition of `Psi1`, your calculations are done with machine precision. Since you are not concerned about precision, you can speed it up more by just using `NIntegrate`

```
(Kx = -(1/2)*
    NIntegrate[
     Kk[r, z], {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.011498, 3.06865} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, for useful answer!